# Bootstrap Grid - why are my column's overlapping only on small screens?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

**Bootstrap 4.1**

I'm trying to create a dashboard. When I bring my browser size down to a smaller view, I expect the div's to be stacking on top of each other, but they're not.I tried changing the `<div class="container">` placements but that doesn't seem to change anything.

If you run the code snippet I think it will show them stacked but overlapped - otherwise here's a screenshot of it overlapping: [Overlapping IMGUR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FNhk.png)

And here's what it looks like on large and medium: [Not Overlapping IMGUR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF1Rt.png)

Is it something to do with the height? It seems like it's not respecting the 100px height that it does when it's in a larger screen width.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Parking Spaces</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Space Display-->  
  <div style="margin-top:20px;"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="height: 100px">
      <div class="col-md-1 offset-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 11</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 10</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 9</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 8</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 7</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 6</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 5</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 4</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 bg-dark" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>TIRE CAGE</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 2</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 1</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="height: 100px">
      <div class="col-md-1 offset-md-5" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 12</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 13</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 14</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 15</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 16</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 17</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 18</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="height: 100px">
      <div class="col-md-1 offset-md-8" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 19</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 20</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 21</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 22</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="height: 100px">
      <div class="col-md-1 offset-md-8" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 23</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 24</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 25</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 26</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Bay Display -->
  <div style="margin-top:20px;"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>BAY 3</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>BAY 2</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>BAY 1</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="height: 150px">
      <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SERVICE 1</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SERVICE 2</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SERVICE 3</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="height: 150px">
      <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SERVICE 4</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SERVICE 5</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SERVICE 6</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `min-height: 100px` instead of `height: 100px`. This will allow your rows to grow higher than 100px when the columns stack on smaller screens.

Buy setting your rows to `height: 100px` you are restricting them from growing when the columns stack and the rows need to grow more than 100px when stacked to avoid overlapping.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Parking Spaces</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Space Display-->  
  <div style="margin-top:20px;"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="min-height: 100px">
      <div class="col-md-1 offset-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 11</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 10</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 9</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 8</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 7</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 6</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 5</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 4</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 bg-dark" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>TIRE CAGE</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 2</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 1</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="min-height: 100px">
      <div class="col-md-1 offset-md-5" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 12</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 13</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 14</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 15</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 16</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 17</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 18</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="min-height: 100px">
      <div class="col-md-1 offset-md-8" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 19</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 20</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 21</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 22</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="min-height: 100px">
      <div class="col-md-1 offset-md-8" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 23</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 24</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 25</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SPACE 26</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Bay Display -->
  <div style="margin-top:20px;"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>BAY 3</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>BAY 2</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>BAY 1</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="min-height: 150px">
      <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SERVICE 1</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SERVICE 2</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SERVICE 3</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="min-height: 150px">
      <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SERVICE 4</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SERVICE 5</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid #333">
        <small>SERVICE 6</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove height
Your code

```
<div class="row" style="height: 100px">
```

should be

```
<div class="row">
```

Comment: This will stop the rows from being the desired height on desktop screen sizes

Comment: make a new class like `.row_{
  height:100px;
 }
   @media (max-width:767px){
  .row_{
   height:auto !important;
  }
 }`
and add this class with row class like <div class="row row_">